# Javascript - value of a modified variable inside a function on recalling the function

Tags: javascript

```
var posVariable = random12;
```

**I am calling the below function by clicking an element**

```
function(){
  ..
  do some operation using the current variable value;
  posVariable = random23;
  ..
}
```

My question is that if I call the same function next time by **clicking** an element what would be the value of **'posVariable'** inside the function ?
If the value would be **'random12'** since its the value of global variable, what should i do to get my **changed value** to for the next calling ?

Comment: Did you check what is the value in `posVariable`? If it isn't what you expected, please add the testing code to your question.

Comment: posVariable is declared globally outside of the function so its state is maintained across multple function calls, if will be whatever it was last set to be, in this case it will equal random23 after the function call.

Answer (score 0):

It will be the last value that was set, which in the case you describe would be `random23`. However, being a global variable, other code might also change the value. If you really want the value to be private to the function, you can create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

```
var f = (function() {
    var posVariable = random12;
    return function() {
        // do some operation using the current variable value
        posVariable = random23;
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you modify a variable (without redefining it in a deeper scope), it will keep this new value until you modify it again. For example:

```js
var x = 0;

function foo(){
  x = 3; // You are modifying the existing variable
}

function bar(){
  var x = 6; // You are defining a new variable in the scope of this function
}

console.log(x); // 0

foo();

console.log(x); // 3

bar();

console.log(x); // 3
```